# gpasswd[29283]: user xxx removed by root from group google-sudoers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-compute-engine, ssh-keys

I added a user xxx for sFTP. The user uses SSH keys for authentication.

All works well for a period of time and suddenly the login failed. The log shows:

`gpasswd[29283]: user xxx removed by root from group google-sudoers`

No one removes this user xxx.

May I know what causes it and how to fix it?

I'm not sure if it is because the keys will be automatically deleted by Google Cloud? I tried to search for relevant information but to no avail.

--- Added Info: ---

I'm not using OS login..

Here is how I setup the user:

**Generate key:**`ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/userxxx -C userxxx`
**Copy and save the private key**: `sudo cat ~/.ssh/userxxx`
**Copy the public key**:`sudo cat ~/.ssh/userxxx.pub`
**Add the public key using the cloud console**: Cloud Console > VM > Edit > SSH Keys

I tried to add the public key using the console again, it works briefly but it is removed automatically again.

Comment: Are you using OS Login? Your question lacks details on how Compute Engine authentication is set up, how you are creating users (the exact commands), etc. Edit your question with details.

Comment: Hi@JohnHanley Added more info, please let me know what else is required. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please include the exact steps and commands that you used. Your edit just contains descriptions. For example, what is the expiration time of the SSH key that you added?

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley I didn't set any expiration time of the SSH key. The info I added is the exact step and commands to create the user and ssh key. Nothing else. From your reply, I guess I have been doing it all wrong. -_-"

Comment: I would not say you are doing wrong. I cannot determine what went wrong as the details are not present to analyze.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks so much for looking at my question and offer your guidance. My setup is very simplified as I'm not an advanced user. I searched that SSH key has no expiration time by default. I tried to search on Google's documentation if the SSH key will be revoked at a stipulated time and I couldn't find any relevant info. I searched for the exact phrase "removed by root from group google-sudoers" didn't return any result. I checked if the server is attacked by bots but I didn't find any suspicious IPs. I don't know what and where else to look at.

Comment: This is what I mean by details: key value when using metadata **KEY_VALUE google-ssh {"userName":"USERNAME","expireOn":"EXPIRE_TIME"}** For more details: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/connect/add-ssh-keys Your question does not show details, only general steps.

Comment: @jollysea  Please provide the required details as John Hanley asked in the above comment.